# can I set the request timeout to zero for forever wait?

Tags: node.js, npm, request

I'm using the npm `request` module, which states in the docs:

> timeout - Integer containing the number of milliseconds to wait for a
>   server to send response headers (and start the response body) before
>   aborting the request. Note that if the underlying TCP connection
>   cannot be established, the OS-wide TCP connection timeout will
>   overrule the timeout option (the default in Linux can be anywhere from
>   20-120 seconds).

what it doesn't state is whether I can set the value to zero, as is traditionally done, to indicate I want it to wait forever.  it also doesn't state what the default value is.

can anyone answer my 2 questions?

*** Addendum I ***

presuming that this module just uses the underlying `http` library, the docs for that also fail to clarify the point:

> request.setTimeout(timeout[, callback])#
>
> Added in: v0.5.9 timeout  Milliseconds before a request is
>   considered to be timed out. callback  Optional function to
>   be called when a timeout occurs. Same as binding to the timeout event.
>   Once a socket is assigned to this request and is connected
>   socket.setTimeout() will be called.

(from: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback)

Comment: It states that setting it to infinity would simply be overriden by the OS timeout value.  Why is it useful to wait forever?  If you have a non-responsive server, this could just leave you to accumulate connections that will never actually do anything.  There are timeouts for a good reason so non-responsive connections don't just sit there forever.  Pick a reasonable timeout that should be longer than any normally functioning response will take or explain why you think you actually need an infinite timeout.

Comment: where does it say that setting it to infinity would be overridden? not in the docs I just posted.  as to why forever is useful consider the use case that you don't know a priori how long a process may take (could be days) and don't want your client timing out arbitrarily

Comment: `the OS-wide TCP connection timeout will overrule the timeout option`

Comment: Waiting days for a response on a connection is not a good design.  If the connection is interrupted once in that time, you would lose the whole transaction.

Comment: the OS-wide timeout only applies if the TCP connection could not be established.  this is not the case I'm concerned with.  I do establish a connection but the request takes a long time

Comment: If you really have something that takes that long, then you shouldn't be using a single HTTP request/response.  You should either use something like a socket.io connection that is meant to be continuously connected for long durations, bidirectional (so the server can send you updates at any time) and auto-reconnecting or design a scheme where the server can give you an idea when you should next check back for more data.

Comment: I can run my requests under screen so that the connection doesn't get interrupted.  as for whether there are alternative designs, sure but my question concerns capability, not design

Comment: FYI, if you do research on HTTP long polling, you will find that nobody expects an HTTP connection to remain open for a very long time and thus why HTTP long polling waits only for a certain time period, then drops the connection and starts a new one.  Network infrastructure like proxies and firewalls are likely to clean up long running HTTP connections that have no activity.  The networking world is not configured to allow HTTP connections to just sit there for days.

Comment: If you control the entire network path between the two endpoints, including both the client and server and all network hardware in between, you might be able to make it work, but it's going against the grain of what HTTP is designed for.  If you have to use HTTP rather than something designed for long lived connections like webSocket/socket.io, then let the HTTP connection timeout and invent a system whereby you can check back regularly looking for the response whenever it is finally done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140013/discussion-between-ekkis-and-jfriend00).